# Server not accepting gzip encoding for GET requests

Tags: web-services, soap

I'm sending different HTTP requests to a SharePoint server, always inserting a header to request compression, but it only works on POST requests to web services, not for GET requests for actual files:

if request includes:

```
POST /teams/.../_vti_bin/Lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
```

then the response I get includes:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

and the data transferred is much less than without compression

if the request includes:

```
GET /teams/.../Report.doc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
```

then the response I get doesn't include a Content-Encoding header and the amount of data transferred suggests that it has not been compressed

The SharePoint server is the same in both cases, and this happens when using Apache HttpClient or cURL

Answer (score 1):

You may need to configure the IIS settings for GZIP compression.  You can do it via the command line or the the IIS Manager.  Here is one good article about it on NothingButSharePoint: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/SharePoint-Compression-in-IIS.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I can't change the IIS settings (we are just users of those services). But anyway, that should enable or disable compression for all kind of requests, still doesn't explain why some requests work and others don't